# Why is this code just deleting the whole contents of the file?

Tags: python

I am making a code that checks if a certain user name is in a text file.
If it is, it stores the score. However, once it reaches more than 3 scores it deletes the oldest to maintain it at 3 scores.

Here is my code:

```
if userclass=="1":
   filefordataclass1 = open("Class1scores.txt", "a"); #this opens/creates a new text file
   filefordataclass1.write(str(username) + ":" + str(score))#this converts the
   filefordataclass1.write("\n")
   user_scores = {}
   with open("Class1scores.txt", "r+")as file:
        file.seek(0)
        scores = file.readlines()
        for line in scores:
           name, scores = line.rstrip('\n').split(':',1)
           if name not in user_scores:
              user_scores[name] = deque(maxlen=3)
           temp_q = user_scores[name]
           temp_q.append(str(score))
           user_scores[name] = temp_q
   filehandle=open("Class1scores.txt", "w")
   for key, values in user_scores.items():
           filehandle.write(name + ',')
           filehandle.write(','.join(list(values)) + '\n')

filehandle.close()# Initialize score list

filefordataclass1.close
```

If you can tell me what is wrong with the python code and how to fix it It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your code is full of errors: you don't close `filefordataclass1` before reading again. You never user `scores` but save the same `score` for each `name`. You write comma separated name but expect an `:`-separated one. Your indentation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Don't chance your file multiple times. First read the contents, then add the new score, then write everything:

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque

if userclass=="1":
   user_scores = defaultdict(lambda: deque(maxlen=3))
   with open("Class1scores.txt", "r") as lines:
       for line in lines:
           name, scores = line.rstrip('\n').split(':',1)
           user_scores[name].extend(scores.split(','))

   user_scores[username].append(str(score))

   with open("Class1scores.txt", "w") as output:
       for key, values in user_scores.items():
           filehandle.write('%s:%s\n' % (key, ','.join(list(values))))
```

Otherwise you are lost in searching for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should open the output file with "a"  (append)  instead of "w" (write).

Answer (score 0):

no need to open the file again in write mode as you have already opened the file in read/write mode with r+.Use seek and truncate after storing the file data in variable. Code is as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque

userclass = "1"

if userclass=="1":
    user_scores = defaultdict(lambda: deque(maxlen=3))
    f = open("Class1scores.txt", "r+")
    lines = f.readlines()
    print lines
    for line in lines:
        name, scores = line.rstrip().split(':')
        user_scores[name].extend(scores.split(','))
    if len(user_scores) > 0:
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()
        for key, values in user_scores.items():
            f.write('%s:%s\n' % (key, ','.join(list(values))))
    f.close()
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: you are pretty good in cloning my answer, but missed out the main part: adding the new `score` of `username`.

Comment: hmm good catch there but OP's question is regarding reading and writing file operations(deletes whole content of file), which has been explained in my answer. i could have just skip the internals with ..<code>. Main point was to highlight reading and writing the file in one go.